# Commutative permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Observation: Two disjoint permutations are commutative. For e.g $\ (1357)\in S_8$ and $\ (2468)\in S_8$.
Formulate and prove(if possible) a Theorem generalizing your observation about commutative permutations.

Attempt of a solution:

Theorem: Two disjoint permutations commute

Proof: I am  unable to prove the theorem. I can only show examples. Can anyone prove this theorem without examples?

Comment: Write down two disjoint cycles as $(a_1 \ldots a_n)$, $(b_1 \ldots b_m)$, and show that they commute

Comment: How about using matrices to represents the permutation, (Defined on $S_8$) , with zero submatrices ,and showing these commute under multiplication?

Comment: I tried writing out the cycles,as both permutations and matrices but I'm not finding a logical way to show they actually commute

Comment: I think it would be a bit more standard to say "commuting permutations".  An operation may be commutative or not; a particular pair of members of its domain may commute with each other or not.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Look at some $a\in[n]$ and denote the permutation as $$\pi=c_{1}c_{2}$$
where $c_{i}$ are two disjoint circles.

Consider the following cases: $$c_{1}(a)\neq a,c_{2}(a)\neq a,c_{1}(a)=c_{2}(a)=a$$

Do you see why the cases are disjoint and it must be the case that
exactly one of them holds ?

Can you continue from here ?

Comment: No I can't, but thanks for sharing anyway.

Comment: @user159519 - Please try a little bit more and write down what you tried so I can better direct you. I think it will help more then writing down the answer..

Comment: Ok I will work on it , but I don't understand why u said a must be n element of [n]

Comment: @user159519 - I am working with $G=S_n$

Answer (score 0):

You can write the permutations as matrices ("acting" on the vector (1 2...8)) , and show that the two commute when multiplied; not too hard, since you will have blocks of identity submatrices